# MDX iif condition only on not empty cells

Tags: excel, pivot, mdx, msbi

How do I combine and iif condition with the fact that it should only be valid for cells with values?
Concretely I have a column where I identify the difference between column A and B. Now I want to define a threshold and show a YES or a NO whenever the threshold is met. For values with blank or zero, conditions should not be applied and row should not appear.
Any idea to solve?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the meaning of `mdx` or `msbi`, so I have no idea if you are talking about a formula or about VBA programming, but I can tell you that there is the following function to solve your problem:

```
=ISBLANK(...)
```

This function verifies if something is written inside an Excel cell or not. In case you are working with VBA, you can access this function as follows:

```
WorksheetFunction.ISBLANK(...)
```

Good luck